# BST Data Structure -- Class project -- accessing nested classes

Tags: java, search, binary-search-tree

The problem: apply a binary search tree to a "person" object isntead of a **int** value. The person object is composed of a name and a weight. The value of the person object that the tree will organize and search on is the "name" (string) of a person.

Here is a (leaf) tree Node:

```
 public class Node {
   private Node leftChild;
   private Node rightChild;
   private Node parent;
   private Person person;
   private int height;

   public Node(Node p, Node l, Node r, Person paul, int h) {
     leftChild = l;
     rightChild = r;
     person = paul;
     height = h;
     parent = p;
   }

   public Node(Person paul, Node p) {
     this(p, null, null, paul, 0);
   }

   public Node (Person paul) {
     this(null, null, null, paul, 0);
   }

   public boolean isBalanced() {
     if(leftChild == null && rightChild == null)
       return true;
     else if (leftChild == null)
       return rightChild.getHeight() == 0;
     else if (rightChild == null)
       return leftChild.getHeight() == 0;

      return Math.abs(leftChild.getHeight()- rightChild.getHeight()) < 2;
   }

   public void setParent(Person parent) {
     parent = new Person( parent.getName(), parent.getWeight());
   }

   public Node getParent() {
     return parent;
   }

   public void setLeftChild(Node leftChild) {
     this.leftChild = leftChild;
   }

   public Node getLeftChild() {
     return leftChild;
   }

   public void setRightChild(Node rightChild) {
     this.rightChild = rightChild;
   }

   public Node getRightChild() {
     return rightChild;
   }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
      Person = new Person(person.getName(), person.getWeight());
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
      return new Person(person.getName(), person.getWeight());
    }

 public void setHeight() {
  if(leftChild == null && rightChild == null)
   height = 0;
  else if (leftChild == null)
   height = rightChild.getHeight() + 1;
  else if (rightChild == null)
   height = leftChild.getHeight() + 1;
  else
   height= leftChild.getHeight() >= rightChild.getHeight()?
     leftChild.getHeight() + 1: rightChild.getHeight() +1;
 }

 public int getHeight() {
  setHeight();
  return height;
 }
}
```

Here is the BinarySearchTree:

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
 private Node root;

 public BinarySearchTree(Node root) {
  this.root = root;
 }
 public BinarySearchTree() {
  this.root = (Node)null;
 }

 void setRoot(Node r) {
  root = r;
 }

 Node getRoot() {
  return root;
 }

 public Node findParent(Person person, Node node) {
  if (node.getPerson() == person)//Error in code here
   return (Node)null; // root itself
  else if(node.getLeftChild() != null && node.getLeftChild().getPerson() == person)
   return node;
  else if(node.getRightChild() != null && node.getRightChild().getPerson() == person)
   return node;
  else if (node.getPerson().getName().compareTo(" a ")  > 0 ){
   return findParent(person, node.getLeftChild());}
  else
   return findParent(person, node.getRightChild());
 }

 public Node insertNode(Person person) {
  return insertNode(person, null, null);
 }

 public Node insertNode(Person person, Node node, Node parent) {
  if(node == (Node)null)
   node = new Node(parent, null, null, person, 0);
  else if (person.getName().compareTo(node.getPerson().getName()) < 0)
   node.setLeftChild(insertNode(person,node.getLeftChild(), node));
  else if (person.getName().compareTo(node.getPerson().getName()) > 0)
   node.setRightChild(insertNode(person, node.getRightChild(), node));
  node.setHeight();
  return node;
 }

 /* in-order traversal for showing inside of tree */
 public void traverseInOrder(Node node) {
  if(node.getLeftChild() != (Node)null)
   traverseInOrder(node.getLeftChild());
  System.out.print("Value: " + '\n' + node.getPerson().toString() + ", Height: " +
    node.getHeight() + ", Parent: ");

  Node n = findParent(node.getPerson(), getRoot());
  if(n == (Node)null)
   System.out.println("root");
  else
   System.out.println(n.getPerson().toString() + "");

  if(node.getRightChild()!= (Node)null)
   traverseInOrder(node.getRightChild());
 }
}




     public Node(Person paul, Node p) {
      this(p, null, null, paul, 0);

     }
     public Node (Person paul) {
      this(null, null, null, paul, 0);
     }

     public boolean isBalanced() {
      if(leftChild == null && rightChild == null)
       return true;
      else if (leftChild == null)
       return rightChild.getHeight() == 0;
      else if (rightChild == null)
       return leftChild.getHeight() == 0;

      return Math.abs(leftChild.getHeight()- rightChild.getHeight()) < 2;
     }

     public void setParent(Person parent) {
      parent = new Person( parent.getName(), parent.getWeight());

     //or is the parent supposed to be a null pointer ????
     }

     public Node getParent() {
      return parent;
     }

     public void setLeftChild(Node leftChild) {
          this.leftChild = leftChild;
         }

         public Node getLeftChild() {
          return leftChild;
         }

         public void setRightChild(Node rightChild) {
          this.rightChild = rightChild;
         }

         public Node getRightChild() {
          return rightChild;
         }

     public void setPerson(Person Person) {
     Person = new Person(person.getName(), person.getWeight());
     }

     public Person getPerson() {
         return new Person(person.getName(), person.getWeight());

     }

     public void setHeight() {
      if(leftChild == null && rightChild == null)
       height = 0;
      else if (leftChild == null)
       height = rightChild.getHeight() + 1;
      else if (rightChild == null)
       height = leftChild.getHeight() + 1;
      else
       height= leftChild.getHeight() >= rightChild.getHeight()?
         leftChild.getHeight() + 1: rightChild.getHeight() +1;
     }

     public int getHeight() {
      setHeight();
      return height;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

```
if (node.getPerson() == person)
```

tests if these objects have the same address in memory, not if they have the same "logical" value. You should replace with:

```
if (node.getPerson().getName().equals(person.getName()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.compareTo()` with person names' as the parameters.

Comment: Hmmm...This didn't work so well. I can't figure out which strings to compare? one of the object being created....and what is the object reference of the string already created? the root?

Comment: You're using `Person.name` as the keys for your BST, so instead of comparing the input integer value with the current node's integer value, you want to compare input person's name with the current node's person's name.

Comment: where is input person's name and where is current node's person name????  I will show my client class....The people are created from a text file containing names and weights...

Comment: It's in `findParent`. Isn't that your binary search algorithm?